# Invoking Function with Implicit and Non-implicit

Tags: scala

I'm trying to define, what I think to be a "default argument", with an `implicit` argument:

```
scala> def f(implicit x: Int, y: String) = y
f: (implicit x: Int, implicit y: String)String
```

Note - I tried to define `implicit x: Int` as the second argument, but I got a compile-time error:

```
scala> def f(y: String, implicit x: Int) = y
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but 'implicit' found.
       def f(y: String, implicit x: Int) = y
```

Anyway, I define an `implicit Int`.

```
scala> implicit val x: Int = 100
x: Int = 100
```

Then I failed to invoke `f` with just a `String` argument:

```
scala> f("foo")
<console>:10: error: not enough arguments for method f: 
       (implicit x: Int, implicit y: String)String.
Unspecified value parameter y.
              f("foo")
               ^
```

Next, I tried to invoke the `f` function by specifying the argument. That failed too.

```
scala> f(y = "foo")
<console>:10: error: not enough arguments for method f: 
         (implicit x: Int, implicit y: String)String.
Unspecified value parameter x.
              f(y = "foo")
               ^
```

Is it possible to invoke the function `f` by providing an *implicit* and providing only a single argument for `y`?

Comment: implicit is for the full parameter list, not just one arguemnt. You need two parameter lists, `f(y: String)(implicit x: Int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit parameter sections are all or nothing—either you explicitly pass every argument (assuming they don't have default values) or none of them. You need to do something like this if you want `f("foo")` to work:

```
def f(y: String)(implicit x: Int) = y
```

I'd be careful about this approach, though—I'm personally increasingly inclined to think that using implicits for anything except type class instances is a bad idea, and having an implicit `Int` value floating around is kind of scary.

Comment: Also worth noting that the implicit parameter section always has to come last, and that there can only be one of them (which is hugely annoying).